# Difference between assertEquals and assertSame in PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

PHPUnit contains an [`assertEquals()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals) method, but it also has an [`assertSame()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertSame) one. At first glance it looks like they do the same thing.

What is the difference between the two? Why are they both specified?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

I use both sporadically, but according to the docs:

### [`assertSame`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertSame)

> Reports an error identified by `$message` if the two variables `$expected` and `$actual` do not have the same **type** and **value**."

And as you can see in the example below the above excerpt, they are passing `'2204'` and `2204`, which will fail using `assertSame` because one is a `string` and one is an `int,` basically:

```
'2204' !== 2204
assertSame('2204', 2204) // this test fails
```

### [`assertEquals`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals)

> "Reports an error identified by $message if the two variables $expected and $actual are not equal."

`assertEquals` does not appear to take datatype into consideration so using the above example of `2204`:

```
'2204' == 2204
assertEquals('2204', 2204) // this test passes
```

I just ran some unit tests against the above examples, and indeed they resulted in documented behavior.

Comment: assertEquals even thinks that `'0012' == '12'`. Even if both values are strings, they are converted to integers for the comparison! You should really use assertSame whenever you can.

Comment: Unfortunately even assertEquals seems to be picky e.g. when comparing array properties and complains about string vs int then.

Comment: Following marco-fiset's comment, note this behaviour is no longer the case since PHPUnit 4.0, see the [upgrade notes](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.upgrading.html#appendixes.upgrading.phpunit-4-0).

Comment: @coviex Reference is cool, but the URL is wrong (because of closing square bracket)... can you please fix it? Thx!

Comment: Important note on **comparing objects** with `assertSame()`. Reports an error identified by $message if the two variables $expected and $actual do not reference the same object.
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertSame

Comment: I just want to point out something strange. When I do `assertEquals(['test'], 'test)`, I get an error message saying `'test' does not match expected type "array"`. So it looks like `assertEquals` does take datatype into consideration for some cases?

Comment: @KodosJohnson I think it's intended to assert that `$actual == $expected` and the result corresponds to comparison using using the equality (double-equals) operator with standard PHP type juggling - which does not convert strings to arrays or vice versa (`'test' !== ['test']` but also `'test' != ['test']`).

Comment: `assertSame` also checks if the two objects refers to the same object if you are passing two variables.

Comment: all this makes me wonder why we don't just use assertTrue with === and == so we know what is happening without google.

Answer (score 48):

When it comes to objects comparison:

#### assertSame

Can only assert if two objects are referencing the same object instance. So even if two separate objects have for all of their attributes exactly the same values, `assertSame()` will fail if they don't reference the same instance.

```php
$expected = new \stdClass();
$expected->foo = 'foo';
$expected->bar = 'bar';

$actual = new \stdClass();
$actual->foo = 'foo';
$actual->bar = 'bar';

$this->assertSame($expected, $actual); // FAILS
```

#### assertEquals

Can assert if two separate objects match their attribute values in any case. So it's the method suitable for asserting object match.

```php
$this->assertEquals($expected, $actual); // PASSES
```

[Reference](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html)

Comment: While this answer isn't comprehensive (it only covers objects), it's exactly what I needed to know.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Yea, but `assertEquals()` compares `null` and `""` and even `0` as equal.

Comment: Just discovered a hidden bug that was caused by this (tested for `0.0` instead of `null`). I will completely avoid `assertEquals` from now on.

Comment: "So it's the method suitable for asserting object match." -- only if you don't mind surprising object property comparisons like `42` and `true` being considered equal. `assertObjectsEqual` seems better, invoking the objects' `equals()` method.

Answer (score 21):

```
$this->assertEquals(3, true);
$this->assertSame(3, true);
```

The first one will pass!

The second one will fail.

That is the difference.

I think you should always use assertSame.

Comment: I just had this gotcha during test driven development. test passed, assumed the value 3 was being returned but actually true was returned. interestingly $this->assertEquals('3', true); fails.

Comment: Good post, but "I think you should always use assertSame." [isn't the right conclusion for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37653597/6243352) 99% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

As it's been said before, `assertSame` reports an error if the two elements do not share **type** and **value** but it's also important to note this from the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertSame):

> Reports an error identified by `$message` if the two variables `$expected`
> and `$actual` do not reference the same object.

So this test would fail too even though they share type and value:

```
class SameTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFailure()
    {
        $this->assertSame(new stdClass, new stdClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Moreover,

```
// Passes
$this->assertSame("123.", "123.");
$this->assertEquals("123.", "123");
// Fails
$this->assertSame("123.", "123");
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Never use `assertEquals` (and family)<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* unless arguments were first manually type-checked, or you're fully aware of the behavior and are prepared for tests to pass when it treats, say, `true` and `42`, as equal--I can't imagine why one would tolerate the risk of extremely subtle false positives in critical testing code.</sup>

#### For primitive values (other than floats) and arrays

Use [`assertSame`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertsame). The behavior is predictable. `"42"` and `true` are not equal.

#### For floats

Avoid if possible by using integers. If you must compare floats, [`assertEqualsWithDelta`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertequalswithdelta) is as broken as `assertEquals`:

```php
$this->assertEqualsWithDelta(0.99, "1", 0.1); // passes :\
$this->assertEqualsWithDelta(99999, true, 0.1); // passes D:
```

The implementation of [`assertEqualsWithDelta`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/cbd0ac18623faaa7ab738db180871d3166b6dbb5/src/Framework/Constraint/IsIdentical.php#L53) uses an inaccurate approach, as [Comparing Floating Point Numbers](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) describes: `abs($this->value - $other) < PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON;`, so you might want to write a custom function.

Or type-check before calling `assertEqualsWithDelta` to avoid the more immediate issues:

```php
function is_number($v) {
    return is_float($v) || is_int($v);
}

class FloatTest extends TestCase {
    private function assertClose(
        $expected,
        $actual,
        $delta = 1e-7
    ): void {
        if (!is_number($expected)) {
            $type = gettype($expected);
            throw new Error("\$expected type $type was not a number");
        }
        else if (!is_number($actual)) {
            $type = gettype($actual);
            throw new Error("\$actual value $type was not a number");
        }
        else if (!is_number($delta)) {
            $type = gettype($delta);
            throw new Error("\$delta value $type was not a number");
        }
    
        $this->assertEqualsWithDelta($actual, $expected, $delta);
    }

    public function testFloats() {
        $this->assertClose(2, "2"); // fails as it should
    }
}
```

#### For objects

Use a custom `equals(self $other): bool` function and [`assertObjectEquals`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertobjectequals).

#### If all else fails

You can't go wrong with [`assertTrue`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#asserttrue), the downsides being a lack of semantic appropriateness and poor default error message.

Answer (score 0):

assertSame() == Tests that if the actual output and the expected parameter are same.

that is :

```
$this->assertSame('$expected','$expected');
```

or

```
$this->assertSame('100','100');
```

assertEquals == If we see with respect to a website page, i have a page which has 2 'table' so when i run assertEquals i will check its count that the 'table' are 2 by using a count function.
Eg:

```
$this->assertEquals(2, $var->filter('table')->count());
```

Here we can see that assertEquals checks that there are 2 tables found on the web page. we can also use divisions found on the page using '#division name' inside the bracket.

Eg 2:

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $calc = new Calculator();

    $result = $calc->add(30, 12);

    // assert that our calculator added the numbers correctly!
    $this->assertEquals(42, $result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, `assertEquals()` is primarily about an interpreted value, be it by type juggling or an object with an __magic presentation method (`__toString()` for example).

A good use case for `assertSame()` is testing a singleton factory.

```
class CacheFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testThatCacheFactoryReturnsSingletons()
    {
        $this->assertSame(CacheFactory::create(), CacheFactory::create());
    }
}
```