# Please elaborate difference between assertArrayHasKey() and assertEquals() in the below code

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, assert

I was reading a Unit Test and it contains these two functions
assertArrayHasKey() and assertEquals()

Please explain the difference between them by sitting in the context of below code.

```
// Test all basic required params were set
    $options = $getReportInstance->getOptions();
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('AWSAccessKeyId', $options, "Option AWSAccessKeyId doesn't exit");
    $this->assertEquals(self::APP_ACCESS_KEY, $options['AWSAccessKeyId'], "AWSAccessKeyId was not set correctly!");
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('SignatureMethod', $options, "Option SignatureMethod doesn't exist");
    $this->assertEquals(
        self::SIGNATURE_METHOD,
        $options['SignatureMethod'],
        "SignatureMethod was not set correctly!"
    );
```

Comment: Might be this helping you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254180/difference-between-assertequals-and-assertsame-in-phpunit

Comment: actually do i know the the difference between assertArrayHasKey, AssertEquals & AssertSame but i could not figured it out that why this code written like that
Anyways thanks for help :)

Comment: @SulemanAkram maybe you should ask whoever *wrote* this code?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Actually i'm using this example to get through the basics of PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertArrayHasKey asserts if the array has a value with the key you put in. Does the value exist?

The assertEquales asserts if the value is the same as you expect it to be. Is the value correct?

So they both test something else. The first tests if the value is there and the second one tests if the value is the same as what you expect it to be.